# How to run a python program(containing tkinter) on startup

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I want to execute a simple python script that contain tkinter window on start up of raspberry pi. and the tkinter window will appear on the monitor. suppose my simple script is

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried the following procedure and failed

```
mkdir ./bin
cd ./bin
sudo nano script_auto_run
```

then wrote the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python /home/pi/projects/test.py
```

to make it executable i ran

```
sudo chmod 755 script_auto_run
```

edited the rc.local file

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and added the following line before exit0

```
/home/pi/bin/script_auto_run
```

what mistake am I  doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `/etc/profile` and put this line at the bottom

```
sudo python /home/pi/projects/test.py
```

[Source](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html)

Comment: edited /etc/profile.  and getting the tkinter window and all the data as per needed. thank you. but there is one problem that is my tkinter window is in infinite loop mode and is coming in fullscreen. I am not able to close the program.

Comment: @AnupSarkar that is an issue in your program code, has nothing to do with auto starting

Comment: yes the problem is solved. thank you for your help.@Tim Castelijns

Comment: @AnupSarkar, how did you escaped the trap