# Autorun for application stored on computer

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an application in tkinter python and I want it to run automatically when windows boots up for any user who installs it on their computer just like spotify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a python program(containing tkinter) on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205616/how-to-run-a-python-programcontaining-tkinter-on-startup)

Answer (score 1):

You can use task scheduler on Windows to run the script for you. [Example](https://towardsdatascience.com/automate-your-python-scripts-with-task-scheduler-661d0a40b279).
Create a basic task to run at start up then select the script you wish to run.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But this will only work on my pc but I want it to work similarly on any pc on which it is installed. Basically I want to add my application to windows startup by default when someone installs it.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on Start Windows, search for Task Scheduler, and open it.
- Click Create Basic Task at the right window.
- Give a name and a description.
- Choose your trigger time.
- Select the script
- Click finish

Comment: Thank you for answering. But this will only work on my pc but I want it to work similarly on any pc on which it is installed. Basically I want to add my application to windows startup by default when someone installs it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autorun-a-python-script-on-windows-startup/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is what I needed.